# 'No CMAKE_c_COMPILER could be found' with CMake

Tags: c, compilation, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm having a lot of problems with the integrated CMake support in VS2017.

At first I had problems with getting the CXX compiler to work, but installing the "Win 8.1 and UCRT" package fixed it.

Now I'm having problems with getting it to compile C.

```
No CMAKE_c_COMPILER could be found.
```

Is there anything I can do?
I can compile C no problem in the normal, non-cmake visual studio.

Comment: If letters in `CMAKE_c_COMPILER` are precise, then you use "c" for `project()` call. Proper language for C is "C" (uppercase).

Comment: Thanks it works! I'm a new CMake user, I saw someone use lowercase c so that's what I tried myself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If letters in `CMAKE_c_COMPILER` are precise, then you attempt to use "c" string as a language for `project()` call.

But proper language for C is "C" (**uppercase**).